# Grabbing the value of a form input method for a possible arithmetic operation in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, user-input

This is my first question here after years, so pardon me if I break any forum/platform rule.

I am trying to build a CGPA CALCULATOR so I am having an issue updating a variable on user input change.

I am a beginner so my code and description may be watery. The problem is with my `handleChange` method I guess, because every time I make an input (I am testing with the `courseInput` for now), the app crashes with the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Someone should please explain to me in details.

I have actually tried a lot Googling but nothing seems wrong with my code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import './App.css';
class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // this.courseInput = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      courseInput: [],
        courseCode: '',
        courseUnit: [0],
        courseGrade: [],
      totalPoint: 0,
      totalUnit: 0,
      newCourseInput: <form>
        <input onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder='COURSE CODE' value={this.courseCode} />
        {/* <input type="number" placeholder='COURSE UNIT' ref={this.courseUnit} value={this.courseUnit} />
        <input type="number" placeholder='COURSE GRADE' ref={this.courseGrade} value={this.courseGrade} /> */}
      </form>
    };
    this.createAnother = this.createAnother.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  // THIS createAnother TAKES THE CURRENT STATE OF courseInput AND CONCATENATES IT WITH THE newCourseInput TO MAKE LIST
  createAnother() {
    var courseInput = this.state.courseInput.concat(this.state.newCourseInput)
    this.setState({ courseInput })
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    var updatedCourseCode = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ courseInput: updatedCourseCode }, () => console.log(this.state))

  }

  
  render() {
    // console.log(this);
    // var courseInput = this.state.courseInput;
  return(
    <div>
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>
         THIS IS A CGPA CALCULATOR
        </p>
      </header>
        {/* MAP FUNCTION LOOPS THROUGH THE ARRAY courseInput AND PRINTS OUT THE CODE UNIT AND GRADE IN IN ORDERED LIST */}
        <ol>
        {this.state.courseInput.map((courseInput, index) => 
            <li key={index}>{courseInput}</li>
          
            )}
        </ol>
      
      {/* THIS TRIGGERS AN EVENT HANDLER createAnother LOCATED UP THERE */}
        <button onClick={this.createAnother} >ADD ANOTHER COURSE</button>
      
  </div>
  );
  }
  }
  
  
  export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not store jsx elements in your state, but only the necessary data to render these elements later when needed. you also have a mistakes(you tried to assign string to an courseInput whice is array).

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
// import './App.css';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // this.courseInput = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      courseInput: [],
      courseCode: "",
      courseUnit: [0],
      courseGrade: [],
      totalPoint: 0,
      totalUnit: 0,
    };
  }

  // THIS createAnother TAKES THE CURRENT STATE OF courseInput AND CONCATENATES IT WITH THE newCourseInput TO MAKE LIST
  createAnother = () => {
    var courseInput = this.state.courseInput.concat({
      id: this.state.courseInput.length,
      value: "",
    });
    this.setState({ courseInput });
  };

  handleCourseChange = (value, id) => {
    const newCourseInputs = [...this.state.courseInput];
    console.log(newCourseInputs);
    console.log(value, id);
    let courseToChange = newCourseInputs.find((c) => c.id == id);
    courseToChange.value = value;
    this.setState({ courseInput: newCourseInputs });
  };

  render() {
    // console.log(this);
    // var courseInput = this.state.courseInput;
    console.log(this.state.courseInput);
    return (
      <div>
        <header className="App-header">
          <p>THIS IS A CGPA CALCULATOR</p>
        </header>
        {/* MAP FUNCTION LOOPS THROUGH THE ARRAY courseInput AND PRINTS OUT THE CODE UNIT AND GRADE IN IN ORDERED LIST */}
        <ol>
          {this.state.courseInput.map((courseInput, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
              <input
                onChange={(e) =>
                  this.handleCourseChange(e.target.value, courseInput.id)
                }
                type="text"
                placeholder="COURSE CODE"
                value={courseInput.value}
              />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ol>
        {/* THIS TRIGGERS AN EVENT HANDLER createAnother LOCATED UP THERE */}

        <button onClick={this.createAnother}>ADD ANOTHER COURSE</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

this code will probably work as you intended.

Comment: Thanks man! This code works. But it seems to take absolutely a different logic. While I am trying to understand it, it'll really be helpful to me if you can **unambiguously** explain your new approach, probably with in-code comment or just type it out, as I'll be using same approach for other inputs which will not be good enough if I don't understand. However, once again, I really appreciate your time and effort!

Comment: as I already told, you should maintain the state (the data you need) in order to render properly what you need. do not store jsx elements in your state. the second change(`handleCourseChange `), I pass id because you need to know what element in the array in the state you need changing.
this is all I changed. you are probably very new to React so I would recommend you learn from scratch. youtube tutorial is probably a good place to start. I would recommand [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ke90Tje7VS0&t=8s).
if my answer solved your problem please accept it as an answer and thumb up ;)

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again, dont be mad at my fundamental questions. Please see this: I understand all you changed till the handleCourseChange method. In the handleCourseChange, I understand how you spread the elements of the array to make the newCourseInputs. The problem comes while trying to understand the logical relevance of the c.id==id in find(c). I tried to change the c.id == c to c, no syntax error but it didnt work the way it should. Please explain the logic in only that line and I should be fine. Thanks for the link to that video and thanks for not giving up on me.

Comment: To help you channel your response, this is what I know: I know that in that line, the find method goes through the newCourseInputs to return the c.id == id which is [ I don't know the exact meaning of c.id==id. I only know that c.id is the length of newCourseInputs but I dont understant why we are equaling it to id to achieve what. I know == compares two values]. Please pardon me if my question is too basic or something.

Comment: Don't sorry, it's OK to not understand. First you need to understand that when you have multiple elements data stored in array you need some sort of unique identifier so you could access to this element's data and update it. I choose my  uniqe identifier as the index of the current element in the array(which is the length) . This unique identifier is id. Then in the event handler onChange I'm passing the ID of the element that changed so I could change its value in the array in the state. This find method just finds this specific element among all the other elements by the ID.

Comment: I just came to say thank you for that video you recommended. It's really helpful.

Comment: @GeniusHawlah my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

in handleChange use arrow function instead of regular function :

```
class A {
 handleChange(event){
this //  the keyword "this" refer to the function handleChange

}
}

class A {
 handleChange =(event)=>{
this // the keyword "this" refer to the class A

}
}
```

The Difference Between Regular Functions and Arrow Functions : [read-me](https://medium.com/better-programming/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions-f65639aba256)

Answer (score 0):

You're not binding `this` to `handleChange` correctly in `input` tag at

```
<input onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder='COURSE CODE' value={this.courseCode} />
```

You should update `onChange` function to `onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}`

`this` is actually a binding that is made when a function is invoked, and what it references is determined entirely by the call-site where the function is called, not where it is declared. More at https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md

Comment: I actually "bind" bound it in the constructor, by the way, I followed your instruction also, it gave same error. When I removed my first binding and used yours, it brought **TypeError: this.state.courseInput.map is not a function**

Comment: Yup, but that's again a separate error unrelated to the binding issue you originally posted. It may be happening because `courseInput` is not actually an array to map.